# Passing '&' and space javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Good day, sir. I'm trying to pass my JS variable to a PHP function. I don't know how to say it, my English is bad. Please check my script first,

My JS. I only know to change the space.

```
<script>
function names()
{
   var dept=$('#dept').val();
   alert(dept);
   dept=dept.trim().replace(/ /g, '-');
   alert(dept);  
   $.post(
      '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/penilaian/list_dropdown/'+ dept,
      { dept:dept }, 
      function(data){ 
        $('#listnama').html(data); 
      }
   ); 
}
</script>
```

And my php script

```
function list_dropdown($deptcode)
{   
    $newdeptcode = str_replace("-"," ",$deptcode);      
    echo $newdeptcode;          
}
```

When dept value has a space, like "A B", its working fine, but when dept value has an & like "A&C" I can't receive it. So, how i can replace "&" with my JS.

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass `&amp;` instead of `&` for the dept.

```
dept.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
```

Comment: thanks for answering. 

Well . from my table i can receive `WH NAUGHTY`,`MECH NGHTY & LF` and `PROJ`

Comment: @Boby You're welcome. You can replace the & with &amp; as in my answer.